# Remote access from Mac to PC?

Tags: windows, mac, vnc, remote-access

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fast VNC from Windows to Mac?](https://superuser.com/questions/28546/fast-vnc-from-windows-to-mac)

Hi,

What is the best way to connect Mac from PC? I tried with VNCVIWER but it was very slow.
Can you please tell me another best way to Connect.

Sri

Comment: Improperly marked as a duplicate.  Mac to PC is NOT the same as PC to Mac...

Answer (score 5):

Enable remote desktop on your PC and use [Microsoft Remote Desktop Connection Client for Mac](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=cd9ec77e-5b07-4332-849f-046611458871&displaylang=en).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps Teamviewer could help you?
http://www.teamviewer.com/

Answer (score 0):

Are you connecting from the same local network, or across the internet?

If you are on the same LAN, use Windows Remote Desktop if the PC is running Windows XP Professional, Windows Vista Business/Ultimate/Enterprise, or Windows 7 Professional/Ultimate/Enterprise or any version of Windows Server. Microsoft has a [remote desktop client for Mac](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=cd9ec77e-5b07-4332-849f-046611458871&displaylang=en).

If you have a version of Windows which does not support Remote Desktop, try another VNC product. UltraVNC and TightVNC are two popular ones which seem to work fairly well. If those are also experiencing slowness like you indicated, check to see if maybe the network link is having other issues - high latencies, etc.

If you are connecting over the internet, there are several options. One is to forward the port for Remote Desktop to your router. It is port 3389, though you may want to forward a different external port to make it harder for attackers to compromise your network. Another, easier way would be to use a product like [LogMeIn](https://secure.logmein.com/), where you can access the computer from anywhere using a browser-based plugin.