# Screen sharing on Mac OS X is slow

Tags: windows-7, macos, performance, vnc, screen-sharing

I connect to my Mac on the local network via UltraVnc viewer from my Windows 7 machine.  However, the connection feels very sluggish - moving windows results in tearing.  Right clicking something take a bit of time.  It feels as if I was connecting remotely via DSL or something.

Is there a way to do this faster?  Is there a preferred VNC viewer that's optimized to connect to Macs?

Comment: I almost suggested [JollysFastVNC](http://www.jinx.de/JollysFastVNC.html) -- you might want to add the "Windows 7" requirement to the question, it's not that obvious as a tag.

Comment: @Daniel - done, thx.

Comment: To be fair, my experience with screen sharing on Mac is horrendous as well, so I just don't do it. I've favourited this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up installing LogMeIn to literally connect from 2 feet.  Somehow going over the internet with LogMeIn feels faster and smoother than Screen Sharing.

Answer (score 1):

What are the specs of the Mac and the Windows machine? This *might* simply be because your hardware is not powerful enough to handle this efficiently. Also, check if the the drivers for your video card are up-to-date on both ends. It might also be a network configuration (or speed) issue.

**Alternative solution:**

Depending on what you need to do on the Mac; there might be a different way to perform your remote operations more efficiently. For example, if you only need to connect to the Mac to do file operations, you don't need OS X's User Interface. In this case, you might be able to do what you want through a [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) terminal from your Windows machine.

Answer (score 1):

This [thread](https://superuser.com/questions/28546/fast-vnc-from-windows-to-mac) recommends:

> OS X Leopard with its own
>   ScreenSharing client, connecting to
>   another OS X native screen sharing
>   server, does some negotiation on
>   colour depth, etc., so it's
>   transferring less data.
>
> Run a copy of [VineServer](http://www.testplant.com/products/vine_server/OS_X) on OS X
>   with the '-maxdepth 8' option (and
>   '-rfbport 5901' to run it as an
>   alternate server), and connect to
>   that.

The idea is to use Vine Server (OSXvnc) on the Mac and any other free remote VNC viewer on Windows.