# Remote Desktop Connection Works only one-way

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, boot-camp

I bootcamped a Macbook Pro with Windows 10. I can RDC from the Mac to another PC, but I cannot RDC from another PC to the Mac.

Any ideas?

Comment: The error is about Local Security Authority cannot be contacted...

Comment: I already tried these fixeshttps://appuals.com/how-to-fix-the-local-security-authority-cannot-be-contacted-error-on-windows/

Comment: Mac doesn't use MS RDC. It can 'view' but can't be 'viewed', there's no Mac host, only client. Win to Mac you need something VNC-based. See https://superuser.com/q/28546/347380

Comment: As you mention bootcamp you are always talking about the Windows installation running on your Macbook, not the MacOS installation. because when MacOS is booted RDP can not be used  as Tesuhin already mentioned in the comments.

Comment: @Robert it works, just had to disable Network Level Authentication

Answer (score 0):

Different tools will be used if you would like to allow access to mac from computers running windows as the RDC for mac is aimed to work with Windows apps, resources, and desktops from Mac computer.

***Get started with the macOS client***
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/clients/remote-desktop-mac

To remote from other devices to mac, please check following:

***Best ways to remotely access and control your Mac from any device and location***
https://setapp.com/how-to/how-to-access-your-mac-remotely

***How to Access Your Mac’s Screen from Windows***
https://www.howtogeek.com/214220/how-to-access-your-macs-screen-from-windows-and-vice-versa/