# How to make Ultra VNC viewer faster?

Tags: performance, speed, vnc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I make VNC faster?](https://superuser.com/questions/15337/how-can-i-make-vnc-faster)

I am trying to share the screen of a system A to another system B. The normal screen sharing is good. But when i run a 3-D program in System A and try to view it from System B, i see the screen frame by frame. The response time is too slow. My Req. is to show the 3-D program to another person.

How can i make VNC faster, to its best ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make VNC faster?](http://superuser.com/questions/15337/how-can-i-make-vnc-faster)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UltraVNC wasn't made for that.  There have been some efforts at remote control 3D apps in Windows though.  I think [ZeroRemote](http://xrowcc.blog.shinobi.jp/Entry/318/) is one such project.  [Fantasy Remote](http://amamaman.hp.infoseek.co.jp/english/fremote_e.html) is another.  Some efforts at enhancing VNC are also in progress -- [VirtualGL](http://www.virtualgl.org/) seems to be the current place to find information on that front.

Answer (score 2):

Normal performance will be good because VNC hooks in to the system and watches for new draws to controls. The latest version of VNC has a mirror driver that instead of polling for new draws is told when they occur, so it has even less work to do.

A 3D application on the other hand, draws to the entire window. If you have this application running at 640 by 480 and with 256 colours (1 byte per pixel) then you have 9mb/s to transfer every second assuming UltraVNC has no overhead (which it does). You can probably get away with this if you're on a 100mbit ethernet link (max 12.5mb/s) but once you start changing the simple parameters I gave (say you use 800 x 600) then you are in trouble.

Also note that UltraVNC applies compression to the data you are sending, so the CPU also needs to be capable of compressing 9mb/s