# Why is PuTTY fast but VNC over PuTTY is slow?

Tags: bash, ssh, putty, vnc

I am using PuTTY (Win 10) to SSH-tunnel a remote VNC desktop (CentOS 7).

After login, if simply typing in a PuTTY's terminal, I can get instant display echo; however, if typing in a VNC terminal, there is significant displaying lag.

I am wondering if anyone has experienced the same situation and figured out the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With simple terminal you send text and receive text (this is somewhat simplified but close enough).

With VNC you receive *graphics*, in general that's more data (or lots more, depending on configuration).

> It transmits the keyboard and mouse events from one computer to another, relaying the graphical-screen updates back in the other direction, over a network.

<sup>([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing))</sup>

See this question: [*How can I make VNC faster?*](https://superuser.com/q/15337/432690)